# iPhone 6 and iCloud contacts reverted back to an old list

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, contacts

I recently noticed my contacts seem to have reverted back to what they were several years ago. I've lost contacts I added within the last year or so and old contacts I deleted years ago have made a sudden reappearance. I recently updated my iPhone 6 to iOS 12.4.1, but I'm unsure if this has anything to do with the issue, as the contacts seem to have also changed within my iCloud (I checked on iCloud.com). I have had my contacts set to back up in iCloud for years now, and have never had any issues with deleting contacts and creating new ones. I attempted to restore the contacts using advanced settings in iCloud, but the single restore point from September 1st appears to be the same. Any help? This is an odd and frustrating issue.